# Gossip protocol on Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Does the gossip protocol is used only to spread the committed blocks via all peers on the "order" stage? Does it work on the “execute” stage, when the endorsing peers execute and sign the transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gossip component is the peer's communication layer, and it contributes to the block dissemination via having peers distribute blocks among themselves instead of having all of them pull them directly from the orderer nodes.

It works roughly like this:
When the orderer cuts a new block, it appends it to its local file system.
In every organization, there is usually a peer that is selected among the peers in its organization (for that channel) to pull blocks from the orderer, and forward them to other peers in its organziation. The other peers also forward the blocks even further to other peers, etc. etc. and this all happens via a "gossip" style protocol.

I recommend that you read the [gossip section](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gossip.html) in the documentation.

Comment: And how is the distribution of the transaction happens on a "execute" stage, when the application sends the transaction to the peer?

Comment: The clients send the transaction to the orderers, they forward it to Kafka, which orders them, and then all orderers cut identical blocks.

Comment: Are we talking about the "to-execute transactions", which were just initiated from the application, and hasn't been yet processed by the endorsing peers. How the application knows, who are the endorsing peers?

Comment: The application knows who are the endorsing peers either off-band or via querying the discovery service on a trusted peer